# AWS SQS Batch size and messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am working with AWS SQS and Lambda. I wanted to know that if the *batchsize* = 5 and sqs messages left = 3.

Will the Lambda be triggered by a batch of 3 messages or will sqs wait for the message count to become 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html):

> Batch size – The number of items to read from the queue in each batch, up to 10. The event might **contain fewer items** if the batch that Lambda read from the **queue had fewer items**.

Thus, based on this, you should get 3 messages. Lambda should not be waiting for 5.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the quick reply.